# How to give name to image.display window?

Tags: image, lua, torch, qlua

**Give different name for each window**

```
require 'image'
local im = image.load('images/sampleimage.jpg')
w1 = image.display{image=im,win=w1}
w2 = image.display{image=im,win=w2}
w3 = image.display{image=im,win=w3}
```

When I was run that code, I am getting each display window same name("display.image"). How can i give different name to each window ?

**What have i tried**
I have also looked to [this](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/gui.md#res-imagedisplayinput-) link but I didn't found anything for window name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to give `legend="your_window_name"` parameter to `image.display` method.

In your case:

```
w1 = image.display{image=im,win=w1,legend='your_window_name_for_w1'}
w2 = image.display{image=im,win=w2,legend='your_window_name_for_w2'}
w3 = image.display{image=im,win=w3,legend='your_window_name_for_w3'}
```